# Propagating errors through interpolation and maximisation

Tags: error, error-propagation

I have a spectrum of some counts against wavelength, where both the counts and wavelength have a known error. I then have applied a Hermite interpolation to the spectrum in Mathematica. From what I gather, an upper bound on the error between the interpolation and the spectrum is,

$$\max_x |f''(x)|\prod_{i=1}^n (x-x_i)$$

where $f$ the spectrum carries an error, as do the interpolating points $x_i$. Now, the problem is it is unclear to me entirely how to propagate this error into the maximum $x_{max}$ of the interpolation. I am assuming it is probably method dependent, but since I've tried many and they all yield adequate maxima, I'd be willing to go with whichever method yields the error estimate easiest to compute.

Comment: What are you trying to do, is this scientific work? Do you want to do a polynomial fit/extraction of parameters and estimate their uncertainties, so you can have a parametrized version of your data? It is unusual to use interpolation with inaccurate dependent variables; but maybe there is a reason you do it like that?

Comment: @cherub What I'm trying to do is apply Wien's law to a spectrum to determine the temperature, so I apply an interpolation and then find the maximum. Whether it's the right approach is irrelevant; there must be some way of somewhat analytically determining the error.

Comment: @OP: There are several comments. a) Regarding the problem -- the approach is important, because you might not take the uncertainty in the dependent variable into account. Also: if you're only interested in the temperature, then two approaches are applicable:  most simple is an estimation of the curves' maximum, where the error estimation is a bit more complicated. Or -- what I would recommend -- is to fit the curve with the known theoretical spectrum, taking both uncertainties into account, which leads to a straightforward error estimation. -- just as a comment

Comment: @OP: regarding the original question, where do you have the formula from? To me the formula and your question seem somewhat unrelated. From what I gather: the interpolation yields one and only one solution, so given your sample there is one single biggest source of deviation -- figuratively speaking at the point where the function changes the most rapidly.

Comment: @cherub There is no theoretical spectrum available for what I've measured.

Comment: @OP: OK, then I misunderstood. I understood that you measured the wavelength distribution from black body radiation. So depending on the wavelengths/frequencies you measured you either use Planck's or WIen's law, or most straightforward Wien's displacement law.

Comment: @cherub Yes; I divided it by the quantum efficiency of the CCD, so I have the true spectrum of the body, to be able to apply Wien's law.